# Industrial research projects on "mathematical modeling and PDEs"

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, soft-question, na.numerical-analysis, applications, applied-mathematics

Apparently there are several companies in a great variety of fields (medical, biological, engineering, etc.) that need "consulting on mathematical modeling and PDEs" from applied mathematicians.

> I'd like to gain some insight in this kind of industrial career prospectives.

- What kind of projects do these types of consultancy usually involve?

On [J.D. Cook's website](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/partial-differential-equations/) there's a brief sketch of some possibilities.

However I wonder:

- Do they actually need only help with computational problems? Or do they sometime require a more theoretical insight into the qualitative behavior of solutions to certain PDEs?
- Do they need help in finding a suitable PDE to describe a certain phenomenon?

Comment: Seems like an academia question.

Comment: @IgorRivin Why? Industrial mathematical research problems are still mathematical research problems.